# Get Line number in map method using FileInputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I was wondering whether it is possible to get the line number in my map method?
My input file is just a single column of values like,

```
Apple
Orange
Banana
```

Is it possible to get key: 1, Value: Apple , Key: 2, Value: Orange ... in my map method?

Using CDH3/CDH4. Changing the input data so as to use KeyValueInputFormat is not an option.
Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 4):

The default behaviour of InputFormats such as TextInputFormat is to give the byte offset of the record rather than the actual line number - this is mainly due to being unable to determine the true line number when an input file is splittable and being processed by two or more mappers.

You could create your own InputFormat (based upon the `TextInputFormat` and associated `LineRecordReader`) to produce line numbers rather than byte offsets but you'd need to configure your input format to return false from the `isSplittable` method (meaning that a large input file would not be processed by multiple mappers). If you have small files, or files that are close in size the HDFS block size then this shouldn't be a problem. Also non-splittable compression formats (GZip .gz for example) means the entire file will be processed by a single mapper anyway.

Comment: this is what the current implementation do. A custom TextInputFormat/LineRecordReader with isSplittable returning false. Though the files are not compressed (are just plain text files), the issue is, input files are quite large, more than 1TB in size.  I'm thinking of creating a split block to rowid map. Any idea?