# MapReduce Amazon Python Get the line umber of the input file

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

I have several texts and I want to know the line number and the file where appears a word.

I got the file well but not the line number.

**This is the map**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os

find = 'but' #word to find
linesCont = 0

file = os.environ["map_input_file"]

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()
    linesCont = linesCont + 1;  
    for word in words:
        if (word in (find)):        
            print '%s\t%s' % (file, linesCont)
```

**And it is the reduce**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

result = {}

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()

    file, lineNumber = line.split('\t', 1)

    try:
        result[file] = result[file] + ', ' + lineNumber
    except:
        result[file] = 'File "%s". LineNumber(s): %s' % (file, lineNumber)

for file in result.keys():
    print '%s\t' % (result[file])
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What do you get then? `1`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Line number in map method using FileInputFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543827/get-line-number-in-map-method-using-fileinputformat)

Comment: I get a number but it's not the real line within a file, because the mapper get pieces of several files and not in order... so... the number it's not the line number of a file

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/current-line-number-as-key-td2958080.html) is a discussion on the same in the Apache forums. [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543827/get-line-number-in-map-method-using-fileinputformat) query in SO. And [here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/04/getting-filename-of-input-block-in.html) is a code snippet to get the file name of the block being processed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i don't kwon how begin... 

The input files are files txt's.

I don't mind to change to Java but I haven't found samples and I can't achieve to see the light hehe